# Why doesn't this Outlook 2007 VBA work (I'm trying to remove a flag programatically)?

Tags: vba, outlook-2007, flags

I have some code that adds a flag to an email but when I try this code below to remove it, it doesn't seem to have any effect in Outlook 2007.

```
    Public Sub Clear()
        Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
        Dim objInspector As Outlook.Inspector

        Dim strDateTime As String

        ' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
        Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

        ' The ActiveInspector is the currently open item.
        Set objExplorer = objOutlook.ActiveExplorer

        ' Check and see if anything is open.
        If Not objExplorer Is Nothing Then
            ' Get the current item.
            Dim arySelection As Object
            Set arySelection = objExplorer.Selection

            For x = 1 To arySelection.Count
                Dim m As MailItem
                Set m = arySelection.Item(x)
                m.Categories = ""
                m.FlagStatus = olNoFlag
                m.FlagIcon = 0
                m.Save
            Next x

        Else
            ' Show error message with only the OK button.
            MsgBox "No explorer is open", vbOKOnly
        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outlook 2007 doesn't support 2003 - style flags anymore (it maps them onto a task flag and the most appropriate category color).

The flag you are trying to clear is probably a task flag. In that that case, performing a

```
m.ClearTaskFlag
m.Save
```

will do the job.